# Why `missing` and default arguments are not working in functions called by `lapply`?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm astonished that `missing` seems not working in a function called by `lapply`. Assume I have the following functions:

```
.add <- function(x, arg, ...) {
  if (missing(arg)) {
    arg <- 1
  }
  print(match.call())
  return(x + arg)
}

wrapper <- function(l, arg, ...) {
  return(lapply(l, .add, arg=arg, ...))
}
```

Setting `arg` explicit works like excepted:

```
wrapper(list(x=1:10, y=1:10), arg=1)
#FUN(x = X[[1L]], arg = ..1)
#FUN(x = X[[2L]], arg = ..1)
#$x
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#
#$y
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Without `arg` I would expect the same output but it fails:

```
wrapper(list(x=1:10, y=1:10))
#FUN(x = X[[1L]], arg = ..1)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : argument "arg" is missing, with no default
```

`missing` works in nested wrapper functions where no `lapply` is used.
Why it seems to have no effect in functions called by `lapply`?

**EDIT**: Default arguments also don't work:

```
.add <- function(x, arg=5, ...) {
  if (missing(arg)) {
    arg <- 1
  }
  print(match.call())
  return(x + arg)
}

wrapper(list(x=1:10, y=1:10))
#FUN(x = X[[1L]], arg = ..1)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : argument "arg" is missing, with no default
```

It seems that `arg` is neither *missing* nor *accessible*. What happens here?

(I know that I could circumvent this by  setting `arg=NULL` in `wrapper` and `if (is.null(arg))` in `.add` or something else. `.add` is an internal function which determines `arg` by its own based on the input (e.g. `arg=mean(x)`) and I want `arg` in the `wrapper` to document the argument `arg` for the user and to allow the user to overwrite the default behavior. And most important: I want to understand *why* this is not working!)

**EDIT2**: Finally this behaviour is fixed. It was a bug in R < 3.2.0, see [PR#15707](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15707).

Comment: I think the problem is in `wrapper` not `lapply`. Remove the formal argument `arg` from `wrapper` entirely (or give it a default) and it works for me.

Comment: From the documentation `?missing`: *Currently `missing` can only be used in the immediate body of the function that defines the argument, not in the body of a nested function or a local call. This may change in the future.* Does this help?

Comment: @joran: That is right but `.add` is an internal function and the documented function is `wrapper` (and the possible default argument of `arg` would depend on the subset which enter `.add`).

Comment: @Arun: You are right, but this works: `wrapper2 <- function(x, arg) { return(.add(x, arg=arg)) }`

Comment: I'm much curious to know why this happens... I've tried for quite a while to understand, but not there yet. I'll write back if I find something. Or maybe it's time to offer my first bounty! :)

Comment: @Arun: See my answer for what I found out.

Answer (score 5):

First, I'll mention that I believe the idiomatic way of doing this is by constructing a call and then evaluating it. See `write.csv` for an example.  I believe this code will do what you want, using that method.

```
wrapper <- function(X, arg, ...) {
  force(X) # optional; if X is missing, the error message will be more informative
  Call <- match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)
  Call[[1L]] <- as.name("lapply")
  Call$FUN <- as.name(".add")
  eval.parent(Call)
}
```

Ok, now here's an attempt to explain the issues you discovered.  I stand ready to be corrected as well, but hopefully this will at least help clarify the issues, just like @idfah's answer did.

First, I'll tackle the "defaults" issue, as I think it's more straightforward.  This one I think can be made simpler, as in the following two functions, where the second (`f2`) simply calls the first (`f1`).  What we see is that the default argument in `f1` gets overridden by the promise to `x` in `f2`, and when that promise is evaluated, it is missing.  Moral of this story (I think); defaults must be set again in your calling function, if that variable is included in the call.

```
f1 <- function(x=1) {print(match.call()); x}
f2 <- function(x) {f1(x=x)}
f1()
## f1()
## [1] 1
f2()
## f1(x = x)
## Error in f1(x = x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Now on to the missing in `lapply` issue.  Here I basically have sgibb's code, but have added a message about whether or not arg is considered missing.  We have what seems to be a curious contradiction; the message tells us that `arg` is NOT missing, but when the function tries to access it, we get an error message telling us that `arg` IS missing.

```
.add <- function(x, arg) {
  print(match.call())
  if(missing(arg)) {
    message("arg is missing in .add")
    x
  } else {
    message("arg is not missing")
    x + arg
  }
}
wrapper <- function(l, arg) {lapply(l, .add, arg=arg)}
wrapper(1)
## FUN(x = 1[[1L]], arg = ..1)
## arg is not missing
## Error in FUN(1[[1L]], ...) : argument "arg" is missing, with no default
```

What I think is happening is the `lapply` is putting the promise to `arg` in `..1`, so it doesn't look missing, but when it tries to evaluate it, it finds that it is missing.  Moral of this story (I think); don't try to propagate missings through `lapply`.

UPDATE: More precisely, it's something with how dot expansion works.  Consider this version of `lapply` (which doesn't actually work on a list, but otherwise has the same code style); this shows we get the same behavior.

```
apply3 <- function(X, FUN, ...) { 
  print(match.call())
  FUN(X, ...)
}
wrapper3 <- function(l, arg) {apply3(l, .add, arg=arg)}
wrapper3(1)
## apply3(X = l, FUN = .add, arg = arg)
## FUN(x = X, arg = ..1)
## arg is not missing
## Error in FUN(X, ...) : argument "arg" is missing, with no default
```

But when we substitute the dots with a variable name, it works as expected.

```
apply4 <- function(X, FUN, hm) { 
  print(match.call())
  FUN(X, hm)
}
wrapper4 <- function(l, arg) {apply4(l, .add, hm=arg)}
wrapper4(1)
## apply4(X = l, FUN = .add, hm = arg)
## FUN(x = X, arg = hm)
## arg is missing in .add
## [1] 1
```

And one more example; if I use dots, but do the expansion myself, by calling `..1` directly, it also works!  This is curious as the matched call is the same as the version that doesn't work.

```
apply3b <- function(X, FUN, ...) { 
  print(match.call())
  FUN(X, ..1)
}
wrapper3b <- function(l, arg) {apply3b(l, .add, arg=arg)}
wrapper3b(1)
## apply3b(X = l, FUN = .add, arg = arg)
## FUN(x = X, arg = ..1)
## arg is missing in .add
## [1] 1
```

Comment: [This question on the R mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Arguments-passing-through-dot-dot-dot-lose-ability-to-check-for-missing-td4656455.html) doesn't have any answers, but also explores similar behavior.

Comment: Many thanks for this great investigation. I will use your first workaround by constructing the call for my own. There is only one questions left: Why the manual expansion (`..1`) works and the automatic one fails?

Comment: Yes, I have that question too, though my curiosity is sated at present.  My guess is that one would have to dig into the C code about how dot expansion works to truly understand.

Comment: Thanks for all the research and the interesting question, @sgibb. It seems that (formal) arguments that have a default are still seen as `missing` (just noticed this while debugging a function and stumbled upon this Q&A). e.g., `f1 <- function(x=1) missing(x); f1()`

Comment: Interesting, @BenBarnes.  I tried with a `match.call` in your function and your discovery makes a little more sense. `f1 <- function(x=1) {match.call(x); x}; f1()`

Comment: @Aaron: Since R 3.2.0 everything works like expected. It was a bug in R: [PR#15707](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15707).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `missing` in your wrapper, so it bombs there.  In this case, you don't need it since you are using variadic arguments anyway.  Try this:

```
.add <- function(x, arg, ...) {
    if (missing(arg)) 
      arg <- 1
    print(match.call())
  return(x + arg)
}

wrapper <- function(l, ...) 
  return(lapply(l, .add, ...))
```

If the wrapper needs to know `arg`, then you need an `missing` there:

```
.add <- function(x, arg, ...) {
  print(match.call())
  return(x + arg)
}

wrapper <- function(l, ...) {
  if (missing(arg)) 
    arg <- 1
  return(lapply(l, .add, arg=arg, ...))
}
```

### I stand corrected

The following example allows the `missing` to be at the bottom of the call stack, presumably because of lazy evaluation.  I am unsure then why your example does not work... curious.

```
wrapper.c <- function(l, arg)
{
  if (missing(arg))
    arg <- 1
  print("I'm in c")
  arg
}

wrapper.b <- function(l, arg)
{
  print("I'm in b")
  wrapper.c(l, arg)
}

wrapper.a <- function(l, arg)
  wrapper.b(l, arg)

> wrapper.a(1)
[1] "I'm in b"
[1] "I'm in c"
[1] 1
```

Comment: You are right but it doesn't really answer my question. BTW the default of `arg` depends on the subset that enters `.add` (e.g. something like `mean(x)`).

Comment: Did you also see the first of the two solutions that I gave?  Maybe I don't understand your question.  If you have `arg` as parameter to `wrapper` but no `missing` in wrapper, then your program bombs before it ever calls `.add`  Seems logical to me.  If your arguments to wrapper are all variadic, then get rid of the arg in `wrapper`

Comment: My function doesn't *bomb* before calling `.add` otherwise you won't see the output of `print(match.call())`. IMHO `arg` is first evaluated when used in `return(x + arg)` (lazy evaluation).

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected... Although I'm still unsure why you would want to do this.